# ASP.NET MVC authentication for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

This is for an ASP.NET MVC application.  For browser based access on my normal controllers, I'm using standard forms authentication and auth cookies.

My question is how I do the same for an iPhone application.  I have a set of RESTful controllers that the iPhone application uses directly, but I'm not sure how to go about authentication...

I was thinking of having a special Login method that returns the auth cookie.  Then I can use the standard Authentication attribute on the ASP.NET MVC side, but I'm not sure how to handle this on the iPhone side?  Can I store this cookie and have it automatically sent with every request?

Perhaps there's a better approach altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is RESTful you can use an NSURLConnection and send your server the appropriate HTTP headers the API requires.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: I ended up splitting my application into two pieces.  The piece meant to be consumed via a browser is using standard forms authentication.  The RESTful piece meant for client application consumption now uses custom basic authentication.